# Flutter text now showing proper encoding

Tags: android, flutter, character-encoding

I'm unable to properly show apparently UTF-8 characters in flutter...

I'm receiving the list of strings from an API (`Content-type` header charset set to `utf-8`, using `http` package)

I tried to decode it to UTF-8 with `utf8.decode` but nothing changed... In vscode console the characters are shown ok:

```
[STEFAN, Štefan, STEFANOWO, STEFAN CEL MARE, Ştefan Vodă, Stefan Knafl Weg, STEFANESTI ARGES, Sveti Štefan 1, Sveti Štefan 2, Sveti Štefan 3, Stefan-Demuth-Weg, Sveti Štefan 11, Stefan-Denk-Straße, Stefan-Fechter-Weg, Strada Ștefan cel Mare, Strada Ștefan Cicio Pop, Strada Ștefan cel Mare 52, Strada Ștefan cel Mare 56A, Strada Martir Ștefan Mariș, Steyr Stefan-Fadinger-Ring, Boskovice, Štefanikova, Štefánikova, Štefánikova, Budaörs Stefánia utca 6, Budaörs Stefánia utca 7, Budaörs Stefánia utca 5, Budaörs Stefánia utca 8, Budaörs Stefánia utca 2, Štefánikova čtvrť, Brno, Štefánikova]
```

But when I create a Text with the above array as String and I show it in flutter I get this:

[image]

I should note that if I build kinda the same code for web, the characters show correctly...
Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: How about check default Font type?

Comment: I chnaged the font I was using (a custom one imported) and now the caracters show correctly... Don't understand why it would work on web though... Was using the same font on both platforms...